# SQLite - Reading last element from result set

Tags: java, sqlite, resultset

I am using `SQLite` db to store set of data and i use a query statement to get the result set which contains data (e.g.) like below,

```
0,3,4,88,6,66,77,4,3,5,88
```

I use ,

```
while(rs.next){  //rs is result set
if(!rs.next){
// if last element do something  
}   
}
```

By this i can get the last element but every time the loop runs, the result set is incremented twice, once at while and other at if (via `rs.next`). I cant do `rs.previous` as SQLite doesn't support it.

EDIT:

I need to check if the element is last record in result set (not by last record's value because the result set might contain duplicate values also) .

Is there any way i can able to achieve this??

Please help.

Comment: you should be able to change query to return only last record

Comment: @JigarJoshi I cant go with last record value as it might contain duplicate values also.

Comment: @user3164187 I think you need to clarify that point, because the way your question reads, you simply want the last result from the `ResultSet`

Comment: @user3164187 If I am understanding it correctly, if a number exists as the last element but has a duplicate somewhere in the middle, that number cannot be considered as the solution. So, essentially this means that you are trying to find the last distinct element of the resultset. Is that right?

Comment: @kusur Yeah! thats what i tried to put in my question..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope this would help you

```
boolean recordsAvailable = false;
int lastRecord = 0;

recordsAvailable = rs.next;

while (recordsAvailable)
{
   lastRecord  = rs.getInt("MY_VALUE");
   // Do all actions here... 
   ....
  // Towards the end of the loop, 
   if (rs.next)
   { 
       // Records available
   } 
   else
   {
      // Last record 
      // Do actions with the variable lastRecord
       recordsAvailable= false;
   }

}
```

Comment: But you double jumped again, `rs.next`, followed by `rs.next` will move you to the second record before you've even looked at the first record...

Comment: @MadProgrammer: The next rs.next will be called towards the end of the while loop. I have edited answer. Hope it makes better sense now!

Answer (score 3):

If you can't move the cursor (to the last position), then you'll simply need to iterate to the end...

```
int lastValue = -1;
while(rs.next){  //rs is result set
    lastValue = ...;
}
```

This should record the last value you extract from the result set.

**Updated**

This is depended upon your table structure, but you could trying something like...

```
SELECT Column1
    FROM tbl
    GROUP By Column1
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

Which, based on your example input, produces...

```
| Column1 |
|---------|
|       0 |
|       5 |
|       6 |
|      66 |
|      77 |
```

to remove all duplicate values from the query...

**And...**

If you're feeling really fancy...

```
SELECT Column1
    FROM tbl
    GROUP By Column1
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
    order by Column1 DESC LIMIT 1
```

Which will reverse the order of the selection and return only the first value (`77` based on your example).

This means you only need to do...

```
if (rs.next()) {
    // Get value from the result set...
}
```

instead of walking all the way to the end of the `ResultSet`

Comment: The result set can contain duplicate values also..if 8 is last value it might be there at some other position also.

Comment: And?  Sorry, I might have missed the point, you wanted the last element didn't you?